# Thousand Seperator function in oracle?

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

When i am executing this function it is compiled and doesn't give any errors,but when using the function in select statement it is giving error. please help me about this . the select query is like this.

select numericformat(facval,5) from dual;

```
 create or replace FUNCTION NumericFormat
  (num IN decimal,
   decimals IN int 
  ) 
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
 ReturnVal VARCHAR(50) ;
 sPDecFormat VARCHAR(20) ;
 sDecFormat VARCHAR(50) ;
 counter INT;
BEGIN
   counter := 4 ;
   sPDecFormat :='.00';
   WHILE counter<=decimals
     LOOP
        IF counter > 2 then
        sPDecFormat :=sPDecFormat + '0';
          counter :=counter+1;
     END IF;
     END LOOP;
     sDecFormat := '###0' + sPDecFormat ;
    ReturnVal := TO_CHAR(num,sdecformat);
RETURN ReturnVal;
END NUMERICFORMAT;
```

The Error is   Error report:

```
SQL Error: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at "ACC07.NUMERICFORMAT", line 21
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Please format your code. You can't call your function until you can compile it without errors. It has many.

Comment: I compiled already it didn't give any errors. It gives the following message.Warning: execution completed with warning
FUNCTION NUMERICFORMAT Compiled.

Comment: The warning means it has errors that you need to fix. Add SHOW ERRORS after your END statement to see them. Or in SQL Developer find the function in the database object list and click on it to view the errors.

Comment: @AdiChava That is not at all an Oracle syntax. That function will never ever compile with so many syntax errors. It is unclear what you are asking. Can you explain in plain words what is the business need?

Comment: In SQL and PL/SQL statements are terminated with a `;`: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS386 please read the manual on how to declare variables: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS00202 and you need to read how to declare a parameter: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/parameter_declaration.htm#LNPLS1271

Comment: the concatenation operator is also wrong: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS246 and variables are not assigned using `set` http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS00205

Comment: @Lalit Kumar  this is an sql query the actual  requirement is i have to convert it as oracle query  for oracle based applications

Comment: @AdiChava I would suggest you look at the Oracle documentation on creating functions, give it a try and then come back with what you have tried. You need to post a test case.

Comment: @Lalit Kumar ok i will try thanks for your valueble response

Comment: @AdiChava You could start here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5009.htm

Comment: @LalitKumarB i created the function and it's compiled without errors and created package also. when i am executing it is not giving any result just loaidng. the code is like this

Comment: @LalitKumarB    create or replace FUNCTION NumericFormat
 ( num IN Decimal,
decimals IN int
 ) 
 RETURN varchar
AS
ReturnVal VARCHAR(50) ;
sPDecFormat VARCHAR(20) ;
sDecFormat VARCHAR(50) ;
 counter INT;
 BEGIN 
 counter := 2 ;
 sPDecFormat :='.00';
HILE counter<=decimals
LOOP
 IF counter > 2 then
 sPDecFormat :=sPDecFormat+'0';
  counter :=counter+1;
 END IF;                                                                                         20. END LOOP;
 sDecFormat :='###0' + sPDecFormat ;
 ReturnVal := to_char (num,sDecFormat );
 RETURN ReturnVal;
END NUMERICFORMAT;

Comment: @AdiChava, please edit your question and add it there.

Comment: @AdiChava Your function goes into an infinite LOOP, and would never give output, because the counter is never progressed and the WHILE is always true. That's because, your function never goes into the IF condition, because counter, i.e. 2 is never > than 2.

Comment: @LalitKumarB in sql server it is working fine with the same database

Comment: @LalitKumarB Your code is working fine and thank you but i have to use this function in ssrs reports. so that i have to change the Element value every time depends upon the value size right.

Comment: @AdiChava You could take a safe max limit for `'999G999'`. Depends on how big it would be. Please mark it answered, would help others.

Comment: @LalitKumarB I updated my code please see once the error comes on conversion                                                                                      sDecFormat := '###0' + sPDecFormat ;                                       ReturnVal := TO_CHAR(num,sdecformat);

Comment: @LalitKumarB when i gave || in place of +  and TO_CHAR(num||sdecformat) it gives the output. but the output is like 100000000.###00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> counter := 2 ;
>    sPDecFormat :='.00';
>      WHILE counter<=decimals
>      LOOP
>       IF counter > 2 then
>         sPDecFormat :=sPDecFormat+'0';
>           counter :=counter+1;
>       END IF;   
>       END LOOP;
> ```

Your function will go into an infinite LOOP an will never come out of it. Though it compiles, that doesn't mean the function would work fine, since the issue will occur at run time.

The WHILE condition is always TRUE, and the counter never increments, since the function never goes into the IF condition.

You have set `counter :=2` and then your **IF condition** is:

> IF counter > 2 then

How could it ever be true? **2 is never greater than 2**, therefore the **counter is never incremented**, since you have it inside the `IF-END IF` block.

When you execute the function, it never comes out of the infinite loop.

Coming to your requirement,

> Thousand Seperator function in oracle?

Why do you want to reinvent the wheel when Oracle already provides you the thousand separator.

From documentation,

- Element    : G
- Example    : 9G999
- Description   : Returns in the specified position the group separator (the current value of the NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTER parameter). You can specify multiple group separators in a number format model.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(sal,'999G999') FROM emp;

TO_CHAR(
--------
     800
   1,600
   1,250
   2,975
   1,250
   2,850
   2,450
   3,000
   5,000
   1,500
   1,100
     950
   3,000
   1,300

14 rows selected.
```

If you want the function name to be same as that of **SQL Server** function, then just create a user-defined function in Oracle database with the same name. The logic would be same as the above query.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NumericFormat(
  2        col NUMBER)
  3      RETURN VARCHAR2
  4    AS
  5      o_num VARCHAR2(20);
  6  BEGIN
  7      o_num:=TO_CHAR(col,'999G999');
  8      RETURN o_num;
  9  END;
 10  /

Function created.

SQL>
SQL> sho err
No errors.
SQL>
```

Let's execute the **function**:

```
SQL> SELECT NumericFormat(sal) FROM emp;

NUMERICFORMAT(SAL)
----------------------------------------------
     800
   1,600
   1,250
   2,975
   1,250
   2,850
   2,450
   3,000
   5,000
   1,500
   1,100
     950
   3,000
   1,300

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```