# How can I alter data type and datas in it, numbers separated with comma

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table , that has field named AMOUNT , amount takes number, table has 1.4m records, i need to upgrade them all . I would like the change NUMBER to varchar and make look like amount datas comma separated , eg: 76543-> 76,543. How can I able to do it?

Comment: It is almost certainly a mistake to change the data type of the column in the table.  `amount` is a thing that you are likely to be doing math on.  You can't calculate 20% of the string '76,543' like you can the number 76543.  You can't add the string '1,234' to the string '6,789' like you can add the numbers 1234 and 6789.  Formatting numbers is something one does at the presentation layer as part of presenting a report to users not something one does in the data model.

Comment: That table will use only for display , all datas will be writing on excel or smh else, that's why I want amount data look like with commas, but I couldnt do while data type was NUMBER, if there is other option for it  actualy its true question over here.

Comment: Thanks to showing how bad this idea :D I figure it out ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i need to upgrade them all

Don't; if you have a numeric value then store it as a `NUMBER`.

> I would like the change `NUMBER` to `varchar` and make look like amount datas comma separated , eg: 76543-> 76,543. How can I able to do it?

Just change how you are **displaying** the value rather than changing how you are **storing** the value.

If you have the table and data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( amount NUMBER(12,0) );
INSERT INTO table_name ( amount ) VALUES ( 76543 );
```

If you want to do it in a `SELECT` statement then use `TO_CHAR` and include sufficient digits to format the largest number you can hold:

```sql
SELECT amount,
       TO_CHAR(amount, 'FM999G999G999G990') AS formatted_amount
FROM   table_name;
```

Outputs:

> | AMOUNT | FORMATTED_AMOUNT |
> | --- | --- |
> | 76543 | 76,543 |

If you want to do that in the table then add a virtual column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD formatted_amount VARCHAR2(16)
                       GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( TO_CHAR(amount, 'FM999G999G999G990') );
```

Then, after adding the virtual column:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

Outputs:

> | AMOUNT | FORMATTED_AMOUNT |
> | --- | --- |
> | 76543 | 76,543 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=844dee035c082af5445f0bb100f2fe74)*

Comment: Actually i need to display with commas but all values, i joined 4 tables . and takes field for each, i ll use them for writing some file , that's why i want to make amount looks like with commas. First I thought like switching data type makes easier but i'll try these thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1 - Create the new column at the end of the table.

2 - Run an update to populate the new table column
(in this step for thousand seperataor look [Thousand Seperator function in oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228335/thousand-seperator-function-in-oracle) )

3 - Drop the old table column

4 - Re-name the new column to the original column name

Comment: Congratulations.  You just showed the OP how to shoot himself in the foot.  I know that is what he asked for, but often it is better to explain _why_ it is a bad idea instead of simply helping implement the bad idea.

Comment: Thanks to showing how bad this idea :D I figure it out ,

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`to_char()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-number.html#GUID-00DA076D-2468-41AB-A3AC-CC78DBA0D9CB):

```
select to_char(col, 'FM999,990;')
```